# Why isn't it possible to convert an existing striped / raidz zfs pool to one with increased parity by adding one or more disks?

Tags: raid, zfs, raid5, raid0

Just to be clear, I am talking about taking an existing striped (i.e. RAID0) zfs pool and converting it to raidz1 (RAID5) or raidz2 (RAID6) after adding one or two new devices respectively and computing the extra parity from the existing pool. Or more generally, converting a raidzP into a raidz(P+N) after adding N disks to the array.

As far as I can tell this should be relatively straightforward (roughly speaking, as I'm sure the devil is in the details), and a more useful feature than the recently added 'raidz expansion', which can expand the capacity of an existing raidzP pool by attaching extra devices without changing the level of redundancy in the array, which increases the probability of failure in the new array linearly with the number of new devices.

I can think of plenty use cases for RAID level conversion (adding a new disk to an old array BEFORE any one device begins to show signs of imminent failure, preventing nerve-wrecking scenarios in advance), whereas raidz expansion seems only useful in a handful of edge cases, considering raidz1/2/3 performs optimally for some specific number of disks (2^n + P).

In other words, it shouldn't be too hard to have a way to e.g. destroy a raidz1 pool, create a new pool with the old devices in a degraded raidz3 configuration, add the two new devices and resilver. Ideally, however, the filesystem would stay online throughout the process of creating the extra parity disk(s) and reshuffling the data blocks.

I am sure there is a technical reason for this missing feature and not just a lack of user interest/demand, but I don't know what exactly stands in the way.

PS: I am aware of the slight abuse of language in the question, which is deliberate and only for the sake of clarity. I understand raidz1/2/3 is similar yet not exactly the same as RAID5/6/7?, but the question remains. Filling, say, a new disk C with C = A xor B and then reshuffling some of the blocks in-place across devices seems like a simple and safe operation with a straightforward implementation compared to e.g. redistributing the data across all disks like in 'raidz expansion'.

Comment: In short: because it's much harder to do than you think, and the existence of snapshots (which are essentially just a list of blocks belonging to that snapshot) in a pool makes it even harder.  Search for "zfs block pointer rewrite".   What you're asking for is a long-desired feature but for now, at least, the workaround is: backup the current pool with `zfs send -R`, destroy the pool, re-create it with the new drive layout, and restore the data with `zfs receive`.  You'll need enough disk space available to store the zfs send backup, either another pool or a (compressed) file on any fs.